# How to access browser localstorage and get a specific item from localstorage using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

How to access specific item from localstorage, cookies using ruby on rails?

I tried using localstorage.setItem and localstorage.getItem . but they are not providing proper o/p

Comment: You can't. `localstorage` is basically a database running in the client and its contents are not sent to the server. Thats not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Cookies in your controllers with [`cookies[:cookie_name]`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html). localStorage is browser-only, you can't directly access it in the server, only through JS in the front-end.